# Show Categories Filter with Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, php, attributes, collection, filter

I have to get the list of categories those have a specific attribute assigned,

So to achieve this i have created a custom attribute boolean type like this:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'top_category',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Top Category',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'sort_order' => 3,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
}
```

And then have created the form field as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="top_category" sortOrder="100" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Top Category</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

It is showing and saved on category level
[image]

Then Created a block to get the categories:

```
class Categories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

{
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryHelper;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get category collection
 *
 * @param bool $isActive
 * @param bool|int $level
 * @param bool|string $sortBy
 * @param bool|int $pageSize
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
 */
public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
{
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('top_category',['eq'=>1])
        ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');

    // select only active categories
    if ($isActive) {
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    }

    // select categories of certain level
    if ($level) {
        $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
    }

    // sort categories by some value
    if ($sortBy) {
        $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
    }

    // select certain number of categories
    if ($pageSize) {
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    }

    return $collection;
}

/**
 * Retrieve current store categories
 *
 * @param bool|string $sorted
 * @param bool $asCollection
 * @param bool $toLoad
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection or
 * \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
 */
public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
{
    return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true);
}
```

Then In Template i have get the categories for now as this:

```
// get current store's categories
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
   echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
   echo $category->getTopCategory() . '<br />';
}
```

As you can see i have added the filter attribute on collection, but still it is showing all the categories not just those which have specific attribute.

Is there anything wrong i am doing, Need help to solve it out.

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind Guys, I was using Second function to filter the categories but i suppose to use the getCategoryCollection() function to to get the filterable collection.

Anyhow i believe the post will somehow help to create it from scratch.

Thanks!